# Disregard default stylesheet for a mobile one

Tags: html, css, mobile

I am trying to code a responsive website. I have used the max-device-width attribute in my head tag but I want the HTML to totally disregard the default css and take on my mobile css completely. Right now it is taking on the mobile css but it's not cancelling out the main css completely so it's pulling styles from it when viewed on mobile when I don't want it to. Does that make sense? This is what my head code looks like

```
<head>
  <title>Website</title>
  <link href="stylesheet_website.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
     media="only screen and (max-device-width: 768px)"
     href="mobile_website.css"/>
</head>
```

How can I make the stylesheet_website.css be totally ignored and take on the mobile_website.css completely when viewed on mobile? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want one stylesheet to be loaded only on devices with a screen and a maximum device width of 768px, and another on all other devices (desktop computers, printers etc), you will need a media query that means the opposite of "only screen and (max-device-width:768px)".

Fortunately, there is such a media query.

```html
<head>
  <title>Website</title>
  <link href="stylesheet_website.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
     media="(not screen), (min-device-width: 769px)">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
     media="only screen and (max-device-width: 768px)"
     href="mobile_website.css"/>
</head>
```

Note the use of the comma to mean `or`.